# Apps cannot read files from Google Drive on KDE Neon

Tags: filesystems, remote, kde, dolphin-file-manager, flatpak

Recently I installed [KDE Neon](https://neon.kde.org/). I was pleased to see the [KDE-KIO](https://community.kde.org/KDE_KIO_Worker_for_Google_Drive_Integration)
integration for Google Drive.

While working from Dolphin (File Manager), KDE-KIO seemed perfect for connecting to my files from work. But the moment I try to access Google Drive files from apps (anything from [Flatpak](https://www.flatpak.org/) basically), I get mixed results. At best, my apps have no access to the network tab. At worst, loading files from Google Drive crashes my apps.

Here is a screenshot taken moments before disaster as I try to load a KeePass file from my Google Drive.

[image: Trying to access keepass DB frhttps://kde.org/plasma-desktop/om remote]

I'm fairly new to KDE Neon and haven't used Linux in ages so sorry for being a noob here. Do I have to mount the remote path, or something, to avoid this?

Comment: Does it work any better with apps installed as packages, or perhaps Windows apps run in wine?

Comment: Google Drive's integration is currently bugged, follow the discussion on https://discuss.kde.org/t/kio-gdrive-hangs-when-adding-a-new-account/3095

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [KIO GDrive site](https://apps.kde.org/kio_gdrive/):

> KIO GDrive is a KIO slave that enables **KIO-aware applications** (such as Dolphin, Kate or Gwenview) to access and edit Google Drive files on the cloud.

Ergo, text-editors, password managers etc. that are not "KIO-aware" will not be able to recognize the google drive directory. I have experimented with symlinking, but that doesn't seem to work either.

At this time the short answer is: a limited number of built-in programs can actually seamlessly integrate with kio-gdrive.

Comment: I am not able to see gdrive files in Kate.  In fact in order to see a Folder, I need to first *Add to Places* in Dolphin which places the Folder as a shortcut in the right tab.  The folder then appears in the Kate file/folder opening manager, but the files in the folder never show-up